# Storing jQuery selector into a variable is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to store a jQuery selector inside a variable but my code is not working when I use it, but it works when I type the selector directly.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
$(function(){
    selector = $('.mtitle');

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        $('div').append('<h1 class="mtitle">Loading...</h1>');
    }
    for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
        selector.html("hi");
    }
});
```

And here's the code that does work:

```
$(function(){
    selector = $('.mtitle');

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        $('div').append('<h1 class="mtitle">Loading...</h1>');
    }
    for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
        $('.mtitle').html("hi");
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you cache a jquery selector in a variable it stores the current jquery object returned.
So, when you first cache the variable, there are no .mtitle elements in the DOM as you add them later.
Its not an error just more of a conceptual problem you are facing!

Answer (score 2):

It’s not totally clear to me your intent, but I *believe* you want to replace all the `Loading...` with `hi`. But when you call this:

```
selector = $('.mtitle');
```

you haven’t stored a *selector*, but a set of elements that *match* a selector. When you append more elements that match the selector with this code:

```
$('div').append('<h1 class="mtitle">Loading...</h1>');
```

the original `selector` variable will not contain references to the new `h1` elements because the selection has already been performed.

The second code works because the selection of matching elements is done *after* the new elements have been created.

But it would work just as well if you removed the second `for` loop, because this call actually replaces the contents of *every* `.mtitle` with `hi`:

```
$('.mtitle').html("hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people have described why it doesn't work, but this is what you need to change to get it to work

```
$(function(){
    selector = '.mtitle'; // the actual selector, not the object(s)

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        $('div').append('<h1 class="mtitle">Loading...</h1>');
    }
    for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
        $(selector).html("hi"); // search the DOM as it is now using the selector
    }
});
```

Comment: But why bother doing it that way? What’s the point of storing the selector in a string? Also, the second `for` is pointless.

Comment: What if the selector string changes or ends up being a list of selectors? We don't know what OP has planned.

Comment: You're right about the second `for`. It is worth pointing out but this is obviously just a small test code to get the selector working for a larger purpose so I will leave it. Why else would someone put `Loading...` to then replace it immediately?